# Deck of Cards (unable to print ordered deck)

Tags: java, arrays

i am creating a card game that needs to deal out a number of cards between 5-10 depending on user input. i created a card class and now i'm working on the deck but feeling lost plus not being able to organise it to display in ascending order.

this is my Deck so far

> ```
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.Collections;
>
> public class Deck {
>     private Card card[];
>
>     public Deck() {
>         this.card = new Card[52];
>         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>             Card card = new Card(); //Instantiate a Card
>             this.card[i] = card; //Adding card to the Deck
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     private void Sort(Card[] deck){
>
>         for (int i = 1; i < deck.length; i++){
>             int nextToInsertRank = deck[i].getRankValue();
>             Card nextToInsert = deck[i];
>             int index;
>             index = i - 1;
>
>             while (index >= 0 && deck[index].getRankValue() > nextToInsertRank){
>                 deck[index + 1] = deck[index];
>                 index--;
>             }
>             deck[index + 1] = nextToInsert;
>         }
>         Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(this.card));
>     }
> }
> ```

this is my Card class.

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Card{

```
private final int RANK, SUIT;
private static final Random GENERATOR = new Random();

private static final String[] RANKS = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
private static final String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

public Card(){
    RANK = GENERATOR.nextInt(RANKS.length);
    SUIT = GENERATOR.nextInt(SUITS.length);

}

public static void SortCards(Card[] hand) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Arrays.sort(RANKS);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public String getRank() {
    return RANKS[RANK];
}

public String getSuit(){
    return SUITS[SUIT];
}

public int getRankValue(){
   return RANK;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
}
```

}

this is the code i use to get it printed.

> ```
> Card card1 = new Card();
> Card card2 = new Card();
> Card card3 = new Card();
> Card card4 = new Card();
> Card card5 = new Card();
>
> System.out.println("A: " + card1);
> System.out.println("B: " + card2);
> System.out.println("C: " + card3);
> System.out.println("D: " + card4);
> System.out.println("E: " + card5);
> ```

this is the result i get.

> A: 9 of Spades
>
> B: 10 of Clubs
>
> C: 2 of Hearts
>
> D: 2 of Clubs
>
> E: 9 of Spades

i've tried a few different things but cant seem to get it to print correctly. any improvements to the code to make it work effectively would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output you expect ? I don't see any use of Deck and Deck.Sort

Comment: i need it to print the cards in ascending order but i haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: Can you share Card class ? so we can reproduce

Comment: Also, it seems odd that `Sort` calls `Collections.shuffle` at the end. And why does `Sort` take a parameter? Shouldn't it work on the `card` member array? If not, you can make it `static`. Lastly, the `Deck` constructor creates an array that can hold 52 cards but only creates 5.

Comment: My advice: have the `Deck` class create all 52 cards and shuffle them. Then make a `Hand` class that can hold 5 cards and sort them.

Comment: i updated and provided my card class. the sort should work on the card array, im not sure how id go about fixing that. what should my Hand class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Card implements Comparable`, that's easy

```
class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        return Integer.compare(rank, o.rank);
    }
}
```

Then the sort of the deck is easy

```
class Deck {    
    public void sort() {
        Arrays.sort(this.cards);
    }
}
```

---

But if you have `null` elements in your array (for now your loop stops at 5 not 52) you need a comparator that handles such nulls

So the `Deck.sort` would look like this

```
public void sort() {
    Arrays.sort(this.cards, (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
        if (o1 == null) return 1;
        if (o2 == null) return -1;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    });
}
```

---

Here's what you would have

```
Deck d = new Deck();
System.out.println(d); // [Jack of Hearts, Queen of Diamonds, 8 of Clubs, 7 of Diamonds ...
d.sort();
System.out.println(d); // [2 of Spades, 2 of Spades, 2 of Diamonds, 2 of Diamonds, 2 of C
```